# difference between two dates is not working in php

Tags: php, datediff, date-difference

I am using the below code to calculate years, months, and days between 2 dates

```
$date1=date_create("2015-01-01");

$date2=date_create("2015-12-31");

$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);

echo $diff->format("%y years");

echo $diff->format("%m month");

echo $diff->format("%d days");
```

This is the result 0 years 11 months 29 days.
But this should b 1 year.

Can anyone please guide how I can get the required result?

Comment: That's not a full year difference so that result makes sense. You'll have to write code that checks these values and rounds up as necessary.

Comment: And how long is a year? Sometimes it's 365 days and sometime it's 366 days, so your question is a bit unclear.   I do not like question with vague answers... 

Comment: I think this question needs to be closed as the solution requires writing code from scratch as opposed to helping with a very specific  issue. Plus the requirements are too vague even if  someone chose to do that.

Comment: Can you please guide me, how I can get this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating two dates within the same year. A full year has not elapsed. It is TO the end date, not THROUGH the end date.

You need to set your end date to be January 1, 2016 as it is not including the full day of December 31, 2015; it's just evaluating to 2015-12-31 00:00:00.000000.

```
// add a day to the end date to ensure the final date is included in the comparison    
date_add($date2,date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 day"));
```

Comment: Is this an answer? Or a comment? Feels more like a comment.

Comment: I agree. Not sure how else to answer it, to be honest, except for redoing everything with DateTime. I don't really like the question.

Comment: But in terms of the account, it is one financial year, from ist January to 31st December.

Comment: "January 1 TO December 31" is different than "January 1 THROUGH December 31"

Comment: @JohnConde edited the answer to include a potential procedural solution.

Comment: @DavidWyly,  thank you, the solution worked for me